# A regex to parse regex string

Tags: regex, perl

I need to parse a regex with regex. I have a regex string:

```
[a-z]{1}[-][0-9]{4}[-][ab]
```

The actual regex for parsing the string above that I came up with and which *almost works* is:

```
/(?|\[(.*?)\]\{(.*?)\}|\[(.*?)\](.*?))/g
```

What does it do can be seen in this regex101 [example](https://regex101.com/r/EhHAmx/1) and the error here is in the **Match 2** and its **Group 1** (`-][0-9`, which should be just `-`).

---

The goal is to match everything inside of square brackets `[]` followed by a number inside curly brackets `{}`. If curly brackets `{}` after square brackets `[]` are missing it should fill it with *null* and this is what alternative group is doing with branch reset group. Also if just square brackets followed by a square brackets, then it's expected to act as later as well (match what's on the inside of square brackets `[]` and fill **Group 2** with *null*).

The problem that my regex doesn't stop on third `[-]` and matches it upto `-][0-9` instead of matching just `-` and then starting with parsing `[0-9]{4}`.

The **expected** match should be:

```
[a-z]{1}
a-z
1

[-]
-
null

[0-9]{4}
0-9
4

[-]
-
null

[ab]
ab
null
```

The **current** match is incorrect and is as follows:

```
[a-z]{1}
a-z
1

[-][0-9]{4}
-][0-9
4

[-]
-
null

[ab]
ab
null
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this what you expect? [`\[([^]]*)](?:\{(\d+)\})?`](https://regex101.com/r/nV1I6k/1). If the quantifier inside the `{}` is missing, there will be no group 2 for that match

Comment: Yes, this is very close, although Group 2 must always present, if missing, it should be set to `null` then. Please make it an answer.

Comment: I see, I was missing this part [`[([^]]*)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/GfXzVj/1). Thanks!

Comment: With [this](https://regex101.com/r/iAEcvy/1), you will always get group 1 and 2. But, in group 2, the curly brackets will also be captured :(

Comment: Yes, this will work too. Thank you for your help! Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
\[([^]]*)](\{\d+\}|)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iAEcvy/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `\[` - matches `[`
- `([^]]*)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `]` and captures this submatch in group 1
- `]` - matches `]`
- `(\{\d+\}|)` - either matches nothing OR a `{` followed by 1+ digits followed by `}`. Whatever is matched is stored in Group 2